# PyQt4: Restart main event loop/ Continue GUI for multiple execution of same algorithm

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am using PyQt4 to create a GUI that reads, processes and saves the processed image. In algorithmic point of view program is working quite well. But I encountered a small problem in GUI programming.
In current state, the application need to be launched every time to process every new image. 
My main() consists of following codes:

```
      app = QApplication(sys.argv)
      window = mainwindow()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

which I suppose is a fundamental for launching application in PyQt.

I want the user to be able to process different images without closing and opening application for each image. I have a final button "Process" to process and save the image. I was wondering if I could emit some signal that would restart the main event loop after all the processes. I have fair understanding of signal and slot but I am not sure how to restart the main loop.

I have looked previous questions and tried some of their suggestions. But either I was too stupid or they were simply not the solution to my problem. I would appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: put your processing code in a function of your own, that is called by the code of the 'Process' button and you're done... No need to restart the GUI event loop, if you don't exit the application it is still running...

Comment: @mguijarr: I has that in my function. But I found out what exactly was my problem. There was a small code that used pyplot to show image (was there just to confirm that the algorithm worked). So pyplot was infact blocking the second execution. Working like charm now.. :) Thanks anyway for your reply